# Magento get the custom product attribute values

Tags: magento

I created a custom product attribute (testattribute). I need to get the values of that with the product collection by using below code:

```
$magentoProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('type_id','simple')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('description')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('short_description')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('weight')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('tax_class_id')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('updated_at');
```

I tried using above code but it is not working. I need a solution without load the product again.

Can anyone please help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Check the attribute and ensure that the property **'visible on frontend'** is set to yes.

You also need to include it with your collection:

```
->addAttributeToSelect('testattribute')
```